# Upgrade R version on Linux Red Hat 6.2

Tags: linux, upgrade, r

I have R 2.15.2 installed on Linux Red Hat 6.2 and I want to upgrade it to the lastest version because I cannot install some packages (like 'Rcpp', 'shiny' and others). How can achieve that? Thanks!

```
>R.version
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          2
minor          15.2
year           2012
month          10
day            26
svn rev        61015
language       R
version.string R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
nickname       Trick or Treat
```

Comment: Hi @MSS How did you install R 2.15 on Red Hat I can not find an .rpm file for this version. Only R 3.1 version is available on EPEL repository ..

Answer (score 0):

[EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has the most recent version:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install R
```